# How do I get back to the fragment without losing data using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a single activity named `MainActivity` which holds the `FirstFragment`. 
Using Navigation Components and  I already set that the single fragment that can be opened from `FirstFragment` is `SecondFragment`. I have also enabled the back button to be able to navigate back from `SecondFragment` to the `FirstFragment`. But, when I come back the fields are filled differently than I left.

Comment: you might be using replace method to change the fragment, you  should use add instead of replace.

Comment: please elaborate more. What you mean by "_when I come back the fields are filled differently than I left._" ?

Comment: Its ui navigation components behaviour it will call oncreateview again when came back to destination